# Trying to use an Observable Object in another class

Tags: swiftui

I want to use an observable object in another class.

I want to use pitchers

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class PositionViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
   
    @Published var Pitchers: [String] =  ["--","--","--","--","--","--"]
    
}
```

in this class then be able to pass it to different functions to validate rules.

```
class ValidationLogic: ObservableObject {

    @Published var Positions: PositionViewModel = PositionViewModel()

     var TempArray: [String];.self//error here

    
    init(){
       
        TempArray = Positions.Pitchers
    }
        
    static func Validation(Position: String, FrameStatus: Bool){
        
       
        confirmNoBackToBack(Position: Position, FrameStatus: FrameStatus)
        
    }

 static func confirmNoBackToBack(Position: String, FrameStatus: Bool){
        
       }
   
    }
```

I have gotten to this point and am now getting an Expected Declaration error on the bold line. Not sure if I am just this last error from getting this to work or doing this the completely wrong way. I can use pitchers in a view but cant see to get it passed to my validationlogic class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid **Swift** syntax, replace that line with:

```
var TempArray: [String]
```

Then modify you init to initialize `Positions` there:

```
var Positions: PositionViewModel
var TempArray: [String]
init() {
    self.Positions = PositionViewModel()
    TempArray = Positions.Pitchers
}
```

Comment: I tried that before this.   If I remove the published I get "cannot find positions in scope. "      If I use the TempArray: [String] I get: "self' used in property access 'Positions' before all stored properties are initialized".     I then tried to make it self.TempArray = Positions.Pitchers and I get "'self' used in property access 'Positions' before all stored properties are initialized"

Comment: Thanks! Now its giving me "Instance member 'TempArray' cannot be used on type 'ValidationLogic'"when I try to use it but looking that up that is another issue. At least I am not stuck. Thanks again!